# twitter connection needs to be closed?

Tags: python, twitter

i developed an aplication built on twitter api , but i get erorrs like   `a mesage that i've parsed and deleted to be parsed again at the next execution`  ,   could that be because i left the twitter connection opened or is just a fault of the twitter API.   I also tried to `delete all direct messages because it seemed too full for me but instead the Api has just reset the count of my messages` , the messages haven't been deleted:((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter's API is over HTTP, which is a stateless protocol. you don't really need to close the connection, since connections made and closed for each request